# How to read a .dat file and write to a text file?

Tags: java, file, readfile

How to read a .dat file in Java and write that data to a text file.
This is my code which i have tried but i am getting error. Please someone help me.

String inputFile = "file.dat";

```
FileInputStream(inputFile));    
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (new FileInputStream(inputFile));
while (in.available() >0) {
String temp = in.readUTF();
   System.out.println(temp);
}
```

---

### error--

Exception in thread "main" java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input
around byte 3

```
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at datReader.main(datReader.java:16)
```

Comment: What is the source of your `.dat` file?

Comment: Perhaps the .dat file just does not contain what you are expecting (not UTF-8).

Comment: Yes: it seams that the content of the file was not written with writeUTF

Comment: Its a machine data.

Comment: does using bufferedreader work?

Comment: I have done it from python and i am getting output as csv file. But i need with java.

Comment: no @XtremeBaumer. Using bufferedReader i am getting output in the format same as .dat file.

Comment: then you should give an examplfe for your desired output and your current input

Comment: Contents of .dat file is like [ÕÏJª?¬?ª?T*X.....] and i want output as in readable format.

Comment: What is "readable format"? Is it a hex dump?  If you know the format of the file do you want to use that information to parse the.  You need to be explicit in what you want the output to be

Comment: I want output simply in text or csv format.

Comment: To get a readable output you have got to know what the input is - otherwise it's just a case of garbage in - garbage out. So the first thing you'll have to tell us is what format the input-file is. And `.dat` isn't a file format but an extension that can be used by various binary file-formats.

Answer (score 1):

Look this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("mydatfile.dat"));
    /* set correct required charset */
    String content = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    // convert/transform here string if required
    Files.write(Paths.get("file.txt"), content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

This code assumes you use Java 8. Most probably you'll have to deal with byte array read from dat file to convert it to a string data.

Comment: thanks for response. But getting same output as it is in input file.

Comment: Please note my comments. I don't know how you should process the dat file data, thats why I mentioned you'll have to transform it